# Cronjob completed but command not running

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, vpn, cron

I'm trying to execute a simple script to start up my vpn after boot with a Cronjob, seen here in the nord.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash
nordvpn connect Italy
```

and when I check the status of the cronjobs it seems to have executed, but does not actually do anything like it used to on an older version of ubuntu.

Here is what I tried in crontab:

```
@reboot (sleep 30 sh  ~/Documents/nord.sh)
```

I also tried it as a root cronjob with this:

```
@reboot sh  ~/Documents/nord.sh
```

I've played around with syntax/sleep timer and have removed/added the sh to no avail. Any help is appreciated! p.s the script runs fine when calling on it normally.

Comment: I'd suggest you use the full path to the script: `sh /home/matt/Documents/nord.sh` instead of `~`. Also, if nordvpn is installed in a non-standard location, specify its full path as well.

Comment: You might want to redirect output to a log file: `sh /path/to/nord.sh >> /some/file.log 2>&1`

Comment: If you put `set -x` as the 2nd line (after the shebang `#!` line) you'll see each command as it executes. Also replace `~` with the expanded path. You do know that `cron` jobs have a different `$PATH` and environment variables? Where's your `nordvpn` executable? `type -p nordvpn`.

Comment: Ah thank you, typing the full path out fixed it!

Comment: @glennjackman Your suggestion worked. You should make this an answer.

Comment: I would also be asking the Nord VPN people if there app has an auto start flag. Many do.